# Can we reuse WordPress drag drop media upload in plugins?

Tags: media, media-library, file-manager

I'm building a plugin in which I want to upload the media.

I'm using `<input type="file" />` which works as expected. But I'm thinking to reuse the WordPress drag drop media uploader.

> **Note**: I have a solution in which I upload the media from popup window.

But, I'm looking for image dropable placeholder in which user upload the image.

Comment: Yes you can. There already a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin/28549014#28549014) . Please do search before new question. Also there is a great blog regarding this topic [here](http://qnimate.com/post-series/using-wordpress-media-uploader-in-plugins-and-themes/)

Comment: I have not cleverly describe the question. Actually this media uploaders open the popup and in which we drag and drop media. But I'm looking for the drag drop placeholders. In which user direct drop the media. Instead of popup. Like WordPress Importer v2. I'll check it. Thanks.

Comment: your answer is here , you can do it simple. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668899/how-to-add-the-media-uploader-in-wordpress-plugin